# when will [UIViewController disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal] be called?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

any example for how to use this?
I can't understand the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only about a view controller presented using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. In that case, a text field resigning first responder will not cause the keyboard to be dismissed unless you override `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` to return NO.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the framework will call it at an undefined time before they need to know if the view controller in question disables automatic keyboard dismissal. Since your implementation of a `UIViewController` subclass (where you are meant to override it) should return either always `YES` or always `NO`, it doesn't matter when it's called.